# How to schedule an index on MongoDB to have it only during certain time?

Tags: mongodb

We are using MongoDB for our Application .
We have got some jobs that runs on first of every month ( Report Jobs) , with the help of crontab  scheduled .

**The script is responsible to query  a particular collection , generate a excel sheet and send a mail of that result .**

As the script runs once a month i guess its unnecessary to have a **index** everytime on that collection , **except during that job scheduled time** .

So is it possible that ,  i can have a index on a particular collection only at that time ??

I have seen the mongodb's feature of ttl , but i didn't see any such option (may be i overloooked)

Please let me know if its possible that , i can create a index on a collection only at that time (first of every month )and remove it every time .

Comment: Why not building the Index before running your script ?

Comment: I see no performance benefit of doing this, infact ensuring and dropping an index in such a small period of time might actually degrade the performance of MongoDB

Answer (score 6):

Building an index via db.collection.ensureIndex is one of the most expensive operations you can run with MongoDB.  I would NOT recommend destroying your index and rebuilding it when you'd like to use it.

There are very few drawbacks to having an index on a collection, even if you aren't using it.  If you were very very pressed for space, an index does take a small bit of additional space on disk.  You can use `db.collection.stats()` to view the sizes of your indices, if you are concerned about this.  Also, writes to the db will take [marginally longer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/) on inserts, deletes, and updates when you have an index.  Really, though, this overhead is probably negligible for a typical use case.

If you really want to ensure that this index is not used for queries other than those run by your monthly script, you can use the [`$hint` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/hint/) to force the use of a specific, different index, or to run in `$natural` order using no indices.